# java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec error while using cfpop in Coldfusion 10

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am using `cfpop` tag, with `secure` attribute set to yes, to retrieve emails from gmail and it's working at localhost but not working at my hosting server. Even enabling SSL using  java.lang.System is not working. I am getting nested error messages as below:

```
> This exception was caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key.  
  > Connect failed
    > Server key
      > Unknown KeySpec type: java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
```

Can anyone please explain why am i getting this error and what is this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes me think they probably do not have either the Cert or the intermediate cert in their Java keystore. Check out this post:

http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/1/29/keystore

To fix it you have to "import" the certificate. into the keystore. Welcome to the world of Java and SSL :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. But now I need to ask my host to import the cert. Not sure if they would be ready for this.